# Client/Server communication is blocked (perhaps by firewall)

Tags: android, ssl, amazon-web-services, client-server, firewall

I have a client/server application where the clients are Android apps and the server is deployed on Amazon AWS. They communicate through REST over HTTPS to keep communication private. The server sits at https ://server.example.com and uses an SSL certificate that I created and signed myself. The client was written to check for this cert and to only communicate with a server using it.

Things generally work very well and we have thousands of users all over the world. However, sometimes I find that the client is unable to talk to the server. I can find this out because I've included a mobile analytics library that logs things like this and reports them.

When communication fails it's either because of a timeout at the client, or an error such as "Unable to resolve host server.example.com".

I believe that communication is failing because of one of the following:

- The Android device is not connected to the internet
- A firewall or something similar is blocking the communication

Why could we be blocked? Perhaps because we're using SSL. Perhaps we're not on someone's White List. I highly doubt we're on any Black List.

Any ideas on how to proceed? Can I somehow determine why communication cannot get through (I obviously don't have access to my user's devices). Is there something I can do to have more of the clint/server communication be successful?

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement a network status checker to log network. Both timeout and unable to resolve host seem to be most probably come from losing connection.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting, can you explain further? Losing a connection is certainly a possible explanation although I doubt that it's the typical reason. We contact our server right away on startup and we've seen failures for newly installed devices. This is odd because you need network connectivity to download the app.

Comment: One more thing to check is are the timeout requests visible in access log on AWS? Meaning is there a way for you to check if a request from App which timed-out did or did not reach your AWS web server.